# How to use SCM Activity plugin in sonar for clearcase

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, clearcase, maven-scm

Changed my sonar for scm activity from 3.7 to sonarqube 5.1.1 as it has in built in scm plugin.

Not getting what are the configurations needed to run that and what to pass in

**setting->genral setting->scm->sonar.scm.provider**

I found this link
http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html
and created a

URL:- *scm:clearcase:baxi_view_4:clinical*

> Error
>
> org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: SCM provider was set to "scm:clearcase:baxi_view_4:clinical" but no SCM provider found for this key. Supported SCM providers are git,svn

and what other changes or configuration needed in my code or is there anything i have to specify in pom.xml.

I am using jenkins and sonar Integration for CI and reports

Comment: ```http://127.0.0.1:9000/updatecenter/available``` Did you install ClearCase plugin for SonarQube? Download and compile from: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase

Comment: _CVS SCM Provider,
Jazz Rational Team Concert SCM Provider,
Mercurial SCM Provider,
Perforce SCM Provider_, and
_TFVC SCM Provider_. These are the scm plugins showing in the available plugins no plugin for _clearcase-scm_ there..

Comment: I have downloaded and compiled the code now 2 jars are created i have to put them on the plugins folder in sonarqube

Comment: ok I put the jars in downloads folder and restart the sonar so they are now showing in the plugins folder and in installed plugin showing the clearcase-scm plugin.but what are the congfigurations i have to do to run this.

Comment: Make sure add this into sonar.properties ```sonar.scm.provider=clearcase``` and re-run Sonar analysis.

Comment: changed the sonar.scm.provider=clearcase getting error:`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cleartool" (in directory path of the project)`

Comment: The machine who runs Jenkins should have ClearCase. And make sure Jenkins can run ```cleartool``` command from console.

Comment: recently found that we need java version greater than 1.6 for sonarqube 5.1.1 but i dont want to do that.which sonarqube version is work with java 1.6 with scm clearcase plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install ClearCase plugin for SonarQube. Since there is no official release download a SNAPSHOT from:
https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase/releases/download/1.0-rc1/sonar-scm-clearcase-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Plugin documentation is here:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/ClearCase+Plugin

Make sure to add `sonar.scm.provider=clearcase` into sonar.properties and re-run SonarQube analysis.

N.B.: We are waiting for positive feedback (on SonarQube Google group) before doing an official release since we do not have Clearcase instance for testing.

Comment: I'm using ClearCase and SonarQube now :).

Comment: I used the sonarqube 4.3.3 and scm activity plugin 1.8 and provieded the scm url and getting the authors of the code but not getting the coverage on new code.any idea..

Comment: What are you talking about? In your original post you said you are using SonarQube 5.1.1?

Comment: yes i tried  on both the version. SonarQube 5.1.1 is not working on java 1.6 therefore i switch to  4.3.3

Comment: Why not use at least 4.5.x that is the long time support version? I see no point of using 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Install ClearCase plugin for SonarQube. Download and compile it from:

http://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-clearcase

Make sure to add `sonar.scm.provider=clearcase` into sonar.properties and re-run Sonar analysis.

The machine which runs Jenkins should have ClearCase. And make sure Jenkins can run `cleartool` command from console.

---

Thanks @Julien H. - SonarSource Team

For running SonarQube with JRE 7:

From SonarQube page:

> The SonarQube Java analyser is able to analyse any kind of java source files whatever is the version of Java they comply to. But SonarQube analysis and SonarQube server require some specific versions of the JVM to be executed.

We can install many JRE versions on our machine. For SonarQube, just set the JRE variable before run it.

Example on Linux

`export JRE_1.7=/opt/jre_1.7`

`export PATH=$JRE_1.7/bin:$PATH`

`java -version`

`/opt/sonar/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/sonar.sh start`

Comment: Second part of your answer is not relevant (starting from "The SonarQube Java analyser...).

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I answer his comment: ```recently found that we need java version greater than 1.6 for sonarqube 5.1.1 but i dont want to do that.which sonarqube version is work with java 1.6 with scm clearcase plugin.```